# Repeated execution of alert from onblur validation function showing value of next input

Tags: javascript, onblur

In the following simple html + javascript, after the alert in function validateDate is executed for onblur event on either of the first two inputs, there occurs repeated execution of the alert showing value of next input as if onblur event is repeatedly fired for the next input.

Is there something wrong in the javascript/html?

```
<html>
<head>

<script>

function validateDate(DateStr) {alert(DateStr);return true}

</script>
     
</head>

<body>

<input name=dt1 id=dt_1 value="15/03/2021" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" onblur="validateDate(this.value)">

<input name=dt2 id=dt_2 value="20/03/2021" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" onblur="validateDate(this.value)">

<input name=dt3 id=dt_3 value="25/03/2021" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" onblur="validateDate(this.value)">

</body>
</html>
```

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4m7pyvdo/

Comment: The default `alert` or any other modal triggers `blur` - if you confirmed the first one and tab out, you are stuck in an endless loop. Use `console.log()` to show the value.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the insight. But the alert is in response to tab out from the input and focus shift to next field after confirming the alert, which should not fire onblur event for the now focused input as onblur event trigger when focus shifts out of the input. Console.log() good for debugging, but what if alert/confirm is required for response from user?